# Update react context provider value using child component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have created a provider that is doing API call and setting data inside provider using `value`

//context

```
export const ProductContext = createContext({
  loading: false,
  data: null,
});

export function useProductContext() {
  const context = useContext(ProductContext);

  return context;
}
```

//provider

```
export const ProductProvider = ({ children, id }) => {
    
    const { data, error, loading } = fetch({url},'id');

    const value = useMemo(
      () => ({
        data
      }),
      [data],
    );

    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

// component

```
const Card = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { data } = useProductContext();


  return (
    <StyledSection>
     <button onClick={}>fetch data with new params</button>
    </StyledSection>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Here in component i want to fetch data when user click on button with different params.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to fetch Data from the value you are given. Here is the way that I'll do this.

```
//Context
export const ProductContext = createContext();

export const ProductProvider = ({children}) => {

  const fetchData = (val) => fetch(`fetch/${val}`);

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={{fetchData}}>
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

As you can see in my context above I have my `fetchData` method there. Which accepts an argument.

**Note:** Make sure you have wrapped your root component with the above Provider.

In my component, I'll do it like this,

```
    //Component
    import {useContext} from 'react';
    import {ProductContext} from '{your path here}/ProductContext';

    const Card = () => {
      const {fetchData} = useContext(ProductContext);

      return (
        <StyledSection>
         <button onClick={() => fetchData('pass your value here')}>fetch data with new params</button>
        </StyledSection>
      );
     }

     export default Card
```

I believe this is the most simplest way you can achieve your task.